# Adding Color Themes to Lispbox

Tags: common-lisp, load-path

I'm new to using Common Lisp and currently using Lispbox.
I would like to add a color-theme package to Lispbox running on OSX to change the color theme.
I'm currently trying to use the command:

```
 (add-to-list 'load-path "~/desktop/colortheme/")
```

However I keep getting the same error:

```
  Undefined function ADD-TO-LIST called with arguments (LOAD-PATH "/desktop/colortheme/").
```

Can someone please help me as to what to do from here?

Thanks in advance,

Cameron

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Lispbox is simply a preconfigured bundle of Emacs, Slime, and Clozure CL.  I think that you might be confusing the Emacs Lisp and the Common Lisp parts of that bundle.  You need to put the snippet you showed into the Emacs Lisp part, i.e. (to get that configuration at startup) the `.emacs` configuration file.  The REPL, that is, the `CL-USER >` prompt, is the Common Lisp interface and has nothing to do with Emacs' inner workings.